# svn command line error "Server certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted" how can i resolve this error?

Tags: svn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server, ccnet-config

I have CCNET build server setup. I get above error when i define

```
   <sourcecontrol type="svn">
     <executable>c:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin\svn.exe</executable>
     <trunkUrl>https://test-server.local/svn/test/Websites/test.com/trunk</trunkUrl>
     <workingDirectory>D:\Program Files\mypath</workingDirectory>
     <username>user</username>
     <password>password</password>
   </sourcecontrol>
```

in my ccnet.config I get Server certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted test-server.local" how can I resolve this error? I am running CCNET with ccnetservice.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using http instead of https?

```
<trunkUrl>http://test-server.local/svn/test/Websites/test.com/trunk</trunkUrl>
```

After comment:

Try this : Do a local svn checkout on the build agent, you will probably get the same error and be able to proceed after you permenantly accept the certificate. Then you should be able to use from ccnet as well. Make sure the account which you are logged on when manually doing it and the account ccnet is running are same.

http://danhounshell.com/blog/subversion-error-certificate-verification-failed-with-cruisecontrol-net/

Comment: Try this : Do a local svn checkout on the build agent, you will probably get the same error and be able to proceed after you permenantly accept the certificate. Then you should be able to use from ccnet as well. But I think the account which you are logged on when manually doing it and the account ccnet is running are same

Comment: For reference: http://danhounshell.com/blog/subversion-error-certificate-verification-failed-with-cruisecontrol-net/

Answer (score -1):

To accept SSL exception for CruiseControl.Net local user account :

Accept the SSL Certificate Permanently

Login to the server hosting CruiseControl.Net using the account that cruise control use. Open a command prompt and type: ‘svn list https://’. When prompted to accept the certification exception, type ‘p’ for permanently.

Answer (score -2):

*I don't agree with the other answers here since they don't deal with the real problem but just provide workarounds.*

If you use HTTPS you should sign the certificate either with your domain trusted Certificate Authority or with some 3-rd party one. **This is the real solution: use valid and trusted signed certificate.**