# Cruise Control Exception : Server SSL certificate verification failed: certificate issued for a different hostname, issuer is not trusted

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol

I'm getting the following error on Cruise Control. This has been discussed in many forums and could not find a solution.

```
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: Source control operation failed: svn: E230001: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://101.17.12.47:11/svn/SOURCE'
svn: E230001: Server SSL certificate verification failed: certificate issued for a different hostname, issuer is not trusted
. Process command: C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe log https://101.17.12.47:11/svn/SOURCE -r "{2015-12-02T10:55:27Z}:{2015-12-02T10:55:33Z}" --verbose --xml --username dev03 --password ******** --no-auth-cache --non-interactive
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.ProcessSourceControl.Execute(ProcessInfo processInfo)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Svn.GetModifications(IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.QuietPeriod.GetModificationsWithLogging(ISourceControl sc, IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.QuietPeriod.GetModifications(ISourceControl sourceControl, IIntegrationResult lastBuild, IIntegrationResult thisBuild)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.GetModifications(IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Integrate(IntegrationRequest request)
```

I have tried the following solution:
[svn command line error "Server certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted" how can i resolve this error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725881/svn-command-line-error-server-certificate-verification-failed-issuer-is-not-tr)

Login to the server hosting CruiseControl.Net using the account that cruise control use. Open a command prompt and type: `svn list https://`. When prompted to accept the certification exception, type `p` for permanently.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to avoid this error by using the host name of your SVN server instead of the IP address.  To make sure you use the exact name as issued on your SSL certificate, you might want to browse to https://101.17.12.47:11/svn/SOURCE with a web browser, and click on the SSL link to view the certificate and see what host name it is issued to.

Then you should update your svn url in the cruise control config to use the host name instead of 101.17.12.47.  Depending on the status of your SSL certificate you might still get other errors you will need to work through.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your Comment. I have changed the IP address to host name. Now i'm getting similar error but bit different.    ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: Source control operation failed: svn: E230001: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://hostname.com:11/svn/SOURCE '
svn: E230001: Server SSL certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted

Comment: Now that you have resolved the name issue, you will also have to resolve the trust issue.  The ssl certificate you are using for your SVN server was not issued by an entity that your cruise control server trusts by default.  If you want ssl to work properly, you will have to add the issuer of your certificate as trusted on the cruisecontrol server, or get a different certificate to use on your svn server that is from an issuer that is already trusted by default.